# Detailed Docker Service Error Output

Tags: docker

If a docker service crashes due to an error in its program, docker generally outputs `task: non-zero exit` with no details. How can I find a detailed output of the crash cause (line number etc.)?

`docker logs` works for containers, but does not seem to work for services

Comment: I cannot get docker logs to work with services -- do you know how to do this?

Comment: [`docker service logs {service}`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_logs/)

Comment: Ah, thank you -- looks like its an experimental feature.